# Location getBearing is returning negative values

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, location

I am trying to get real time Bearings from Phone location.

From GPS we can get direct bearing for `location.getBearing()`. However if we are using cellular network we can not get bearing so i am trying to calculate bearing from old saved location and current location using

```
       heading = mLocation.bearingTo(location);
```

`mLocation` is old location, `location` is new location. However some of its values are negative .

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html
```

clearly tells that values should be from 0 to 360, What is going on around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are moving towards East, your bearing is 90 degrees, if you are moving towards South it is +180 or - 180, if you are moving towards West it is -90 degrees.

Comment: ok, so what i did was added an offset of 180 to convert to standard 0-360, this offset is also added from GPS acquired bearing too. please tell me if its ok, now some values are above 400, so this means i am getting bearing above 200 too. whats going on around here?

Comment: can you share your code here? So i could be help you. or try to use following line

int azimut = (int) Math.round(Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]));

Answer (score 0):

try to use following line

```
int azimut = (int) Math.round(Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]));
```